# Save as Excel macro to save to desktop on Windows 7 or XP

Tags: windows, excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I want to use a macro to 'save as PDF' in Excel 2010, always saving to the desktop.

I have successfully been able to read the username of the computer using 'Environ' function, however, due to the different location of the desktop folder on Windows 7 and Windows XP it will not always work.

Is there a way to get the operating system to be read like the username? Then I can have an IF( OS=W7 , C:/Users.... , C:/Docs... ) to set the file path.

My plan is to display these in cells, then concatenate these cells into a single string and read that in the macro for the entire save filepath and name.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Doug.

Comment: get operating system using API and then based on the result use `xp_Parth` or `win7_Path` which should be predefined

Comment: if you have simply searched in Google for "vba desktop folder" there are millions of examples. not sure why you are expecting we will search and paste it for you. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Function userDesktop() As String
    Dim oWH As Object

    Set oWH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    userDesktop = oWH.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

End Function
```